Fix for "Attempt to read property "nodeValue" on null"
I'm using the following to get  content from a list of feeds (in my example below only 2):
$urlarray = array(
array( 'name' => 'feed1', 'url' => 'https://example.com/feed1/rss'),
array( 'name' => 'feed2', 'url' => 'https://example.com/feed2/rss'),
);

Then to extract the entry details (title, description) with this:
foreach ( $urlarray as $url ) {
  $rss->load( $url['url'] );
  foreach ( $rss->getElementsByTagName( 'item' ) as $node ) {
  $item = array(
    'site'  => $url['name'],
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'title' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
    'desc'  => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'description' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
    'link'  => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'link' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
    'date'  => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'pubDate' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,   
    'category'  => $node->getElementsByTagName( 'category' )->item( 0 )->nodeValue, //this is the issue
  );
  array_push( $feed, $item );
  }
}


But I get the warning

Attempt to read property "nodeValue" on null

about the category line, probably because some feed entries there is no category.
It's just a warning, but I suppose it is better to fix it. Is there something I do to get rid of this, like check if the node exists first?

Please read tag descriptions before you add them! [tag:node-modules] is about the node.js platform, as it says, and is irrelevant to this question - which appears to be about DOM parsing. I've removed it for you c.f. What are tags, and how should I use them?

probably because some feed entries there is no category...correct. check if the node exists first...correct. Have you tried anything?

Per the docs, getElementsByTagName returns a DOMNodeList which has an item method that returns null if it doesn't exist.

"It's just a warning, but I suppose it is better to fix it" - props for say that! Too many people ignore warnings and are surprised when they get bit some random day in the future.

The "just a warning" attitude is probably why PHP 8 turned many warnings into fatal errors.

@ADyson "Have you tried anything?" - I obviously failed, hence I'm asking fr help here

I obviously failed...it's not obvious to us, since you didn't mention any kind of attempt or show us any code that you tried to use to check if the node exists. We're not going to assume you've done things you haven't talked about. But the basic principle of checking whether a variable (or an array element) is null in PHP is already very well documented...we probably don't need to repeat that general advice. So if you did try something, and it didn't work, then you need to show us exactly what you tried, in order for us to tell you what you did wrong, which you can then learn from.

The point is that we're not a free write-my-code service. Well help you with your attempt to solve the problem. And we're an encyclopaedia, not a helpdesk. If the information you need already exists, we see no reason to spend time and effort repeating it. Granted it might have been faster to provide a suggestion than write all this, but only because it's a fairly trivial one. But then quite often if we do that, we find people return with something more complex, but still put no effort at all into solving it.

In your case you say you did try something, but didn't show us what you tried. That defeats the point of stackoverflow entirely.
